# Creating two groupboxes, EOSError 1410 - Class already exists

Tags: c++, vcl, c++builder-6

I've created an empty project and added two groupboxes on the form - GroupBox1 and GroupBox2, so the form looks like this now:

[image: screenshot 1]

As my system is missing C++ Builder runtime files (why? I did a clean install), I'm building my project with *"Build with runtime packages"* and *"Use dynamic RTL"* off. I didn't change form .cpp and project .cpp (they look normal and most probably don't affect my trouble). Header file wasn't changed too, it looks like this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef MainFrmH
#define MainFrmH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
        TGroupBox *GroupBox1;
        TGroupBox *GroupBox2;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
        __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Now, after running the application, I get presented with such error:

[image: screenshot 2]

My project file looks like this (I didn't edit it manually):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<!-- C++Builder XML Project -->
<PROJECT>
  <MACROS>
    <VERSION value="BCB.06.00"/>
    <PROJECT value="Project.exe"/>
    <OBJFILES value="Project.obj MainFrm.obj"/>
    <RESFILES value="Project.res"/>
    <IDLFILES value=""/>
    <IDLGENFILES value=""/>
    <DEFFILE value=""/>
    <RESDEPEN value="$(RESFILES) MainFrm.dfm"/>
    <LIBFILES value=""/>
    <LIBRARIES value="rtl.lib vcl.lib"/>
    <SPARELIBS value="vcl.lib rtl.lib"/>
    <PACKAGES value="vcl.bpi rtl.bpi dbrtl.bpi adortl.bpi vcldb.bpi vclx.bpi bdertl.bpi 
      vcldbx.bpi ibxpress.bpi dsnap.bpi cds.bpi bdecds.bpi qrpt.bpi teeui.bpi 
      teedb.bpi tee.bpi dss.bpi teeqr.bpi visualclx.bpi visualdbclx.bpi 
      dsnapcrba.bpi dsnapcon.bpi bcbsmp.bpi vclie.bpi xmlrtl.bpi inet.bpi 
      inetdbbde.bpi inetdbxpress.bpi inetdb.bpi nmfast.bpi webdsnap.bpi 
      bcbie.bpi websnap.bpi soaprtl.bpi dclocx.bpi dbexpress.bpi dbxcds.bpi 
      indy.bpi bcb2kaxserver.bpi AlphaBlendedSplashC6.bpi FlatStyle_Cb4.bpi 
      Vcwb6.bpi tsh.bpi SynEdit_BCB6.bpi KComponents.bpi"/>
    <PATHCPP value=".;"/>
    <PATHPAS value=".;"/>
    <PATHRC value=".;"/>
    <PATHASM value=".;"/>
    <DEBUGLIBPATH value="$(BCB)\lib\debug"/>
    <RELEASELIBPATH value="$(BCB)\lib\release"/>
    <LINKER value="ilink32"/>
    <USERDEFINES value="_DEBUG"/>
    <SYSDEFINES value="NO_STRICT;_NO_VCL"/>
    <MAINSOURCE value="Project.cpp"/>
    <INCLUDEPATH value="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects&quot;$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl"/>
    <LIBPATH value="[PROJECT PATH];&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects&quot;$(BCB)\Projects\Lib;&quot;c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\lib\debug&quot;;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib"/>
    <WARNINGS value="-w-par"/>
    <OTHERFILES value=""/>
  </MACROS>
  <OPTIONS>
    <IDLCFLAGS value="-I&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects&quot; 
      -I$(BCB)\include 
      -I$(BCB)\include\vcl -src_suffix cpp -D_DEBUG -boa"/>
    <CFLAG1 value="-Od -w -Vx -Ve -xp -X- -r- -pr -a8 -b -d -k -y -v -vi- -tWD -tWM- -c"/>
    <PFLAGS value="-$Y+ -$W -$O- -$A8 -v -JPHNE -M"/>
    <RFLAGS value=""/>
    <AFLAGS value="/mx /w2 /zi /l"/>
    <LFLAGS value="-D&quot;&quot; -aa -Tpe -x -Gn -Gi -v"/>
    <OTHERFILES value=""/>
  </OPTIONS>
  <LINKER>
    <ALLOBJ value="c0w32.obj $(OBJFILES)"/>
    <ALLRES value="$(RESFILES)"/>
    <ALLLIB value="$(LIBFILES) $(LIBRARIES) import32.lib cw32.lib"/>
    <OTHERFILES value=""/>
  </LINKER>
  <FILELIST>
      <FILE FILENAME="Project.res" FORMNAME="" UNITNAME="Project.res" CONTAINERID="ResTool" DESIGNCLASS="" LOCALCOMMAND=""/>
      <FILE FILENAME="Project.cpp" FORMNAME="" UNITNAME="Project" CONTAINERID="CCompiler" DESIGNCLASS="" LOCALCOMMAND=""/>
      <FILE FILENAME="MainFrm.cpp" FORMNAME="Form1" UNITNAME="MainFrm" CONTAINERID="CCompiler" DESIGNCLASS="" LOCALCOMMAND=""/>
  </FILELIST>
  <BUILDTOOLS>
  </BUILDTOOLS>

  <IDEOPTIONS>
[Version Info]
IncludeVerInfo=0
AutoIncBuild=1
MajorVer=1
MinorVer=0
Release=0
Build=0
Debug=0
PreRelease=1
Special=0
Private=0
DLL=0
Locale=1045
CodePage=1250

[Version Info Keys]
CompanyName=
FileDescription=
FileVersion=
InternalName=
LegalCopyright=
LegalTrademarks=
OriginalFilename=
ProductName=
ProductVersion=
Comments=

[Excluded Packages]
c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\Projects\Bpl\A406_D61.bpl=TurboPower Async Professional 4.05 Designtime Package - VCL61
c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\Bin\dclite60.bpl=Borland Integrated Translation Environment

[HistoryLists\hlIncludePath]
Count=4
Item0=[PROJECT PATH];C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects;$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl
Item1=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects;$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl
Item2=$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl
Item3=$(BCB)\include\vcl

[HistoryLists\hlLibraryPath]
Count=4
Item0=[PROJECT PATH];C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects;$(BCB)\Projects\Lib;c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\lib\debug;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib
Item1=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects;$(BCB)\Projects\Lib;c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\lib\debug;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib
Item2=$(BCB)\Projects\Lib;c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\lib\debug;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib
Item3=$(BCB)\Projects\Lib;c:\program files (x86)\borland\cbuilder6\lib\debug;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib

[HistoryLists\hlDebugSourcePath]
Count=1
Item0=$(BCB)\source\vcl

[HistoryLists\hlConditionals]
Count=1
Item0=_DEBUG

[Debugging]
DebugSourceDirs=$(BCB)\source\vcl

[Parameters]
RunParams=
Launcher=
UseLauncher=0
DebugCWD=
HostApplication=
RemoteHost=
RemotePath=
RemoteLauncher=
RemoteCWD=
RemoteDebug=0

[Compiler]
ShowInfoMsgs=1
LinkDebugVcl=0
LinkCGLIB=0

[CORBA]
AddServerUnit=1
AddClientUnit=1
PrecompiledHeaders=1
  </IDEOPTIONS>
</PROJECT>
```

What's wrong there? How do I get rid of this error? If it helps, I'm using Enterprise edition.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the question is tightly related to Delphi (as the problem lies in shared category)

Comment: It isn't. The [tag:delphi] tag should only be used to ask about delphi code. Mentioning c++-builder and vcl is clear enough.

Comment: As you wish :).

Comment: "*my system is missing C++ Builder runtime files (why? I did a clean install)*" - unlike Microsoft runtimes, Borland runtimes are not shipped with the OS, so you must deploy them with your app when needed. "*I'm building my project with "Build with runtime packages" and "Use dynamic RTL" off*"- that is OK. You should do that. "*What's wrong there?*" - I have multiple apps written in BCB6 that have multiple GroupBoxes in them without error. Your problem is related to something else. I suggest you run your app in the debugger and step into the VCL source code to see which class is actual failing

Comment: One oddity I see in your project is the `PACKAGES` list includes `FlatStyle_Cb4.bpi`. The `Cb4` implies the package is meant for BCB4, not BCB6.

Comment: I found BCB debugger a bit handicapped, how can I view the stacktrace?

Comment: Also, I've reinstalled C++ Builder, installing only TMS Controls; it seems like adding any of "Sample" controls bricks entire installation

Comment: Does the cw32.lib library have VCL code? [EOSError - 'System Error. Code 1410'](http://www.44342.com/cpp-builder-f1283-t1773-p1.htm)